# Что здесь делает декоратор?

Tags: python, yield

Я сейчас смотрю описание и примеры контекстного менеджера "with" (он мне относительно понятен), но я не понимаю, что в этом коде делает декоратор? Без него все бы прекрасно работало. 
p.s. еще я не понимаю, зачем здесь yield, если с return код будет так же работать.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def file_open(path):
    try:
        f_obj = open(path, 'w')
        yield f_obj
    except OSError:
        print("We had an error!")
    finally:
        print('Closing file')
        f_obj.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with file_open('test.txt') as fobj:
    fobj.write('Testing context managers')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в самом деле код заработал, когда вы запустили его без декоратора и с return вместо yield? Это очень странно.

Чтобы объект мог работать контекстным менеджером, он должен иметь два специальных метода `__enter__` и `__exit__`. Декоратор `@contextmanager` их и создаёт.

При этом `@contextmanager` должен быть применён к функции-генератору, т.к. ему нужно дёрнуть задекорированную функцию два раза - при открытии и при закрытии контекста, и эти два вызова должны выполнить разную логику, сохранив внутреннее состояние между вызовами. Обычная функция c `return` так не умеет, только функция-генератор с `yield`.